# Get a text value of the button dynamically

Tags: android

My View

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:text="Text 1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Button>

        <Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:text="Text 2"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Button>

        <Button android:id="@+id/button3" android:text="Text 3"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Button>

        <Button android:id="@+id/button4" android:text="Text 4"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Button>
```

I have an undefined amount of buttons and need get you text in a touch event.

How i do it?

Tnks a lot.

EDIT:

Thanks for all, this is result of the your Answers => https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.redrails.torpedos
My App :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you name all of your buttons "button1, button2, button3..." you can do this:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= buttonCount; i++) {
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier("button" + i, "id", getPackageName() );
    findViewById(id).setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Where `buttonCount` is the amount of buttons you have. This method would be placed in `onCreate()`.

Then for your onClick:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v instanceof TextView) {
        CharSequence text = ((TextView) v).getText();
        // Do fun stuff with text
    }
}
```

Your Activity will need to implement `OnClickListener`

Comment: No problem...keep in mind this operation can be very slow though and is not recommended if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text of a button by using the [getText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText%28%29) method.

Comment: Yes, but i need get a id of the button before with a ontouch event... how?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    private Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4; // You can add more if you like

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
         btn1 = (Button) findViewByID(R.id.button1);
         btn2 = (Button) findViewByID(R.id.button2);
         btn3 = (Button) findViewByID(R.id.button3);
         btn4 = (Button) findViewByID(R.id.button4);
         // declare the other buttons if any

         btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
         btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
         btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
         btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
         // register the other buttons as well if any
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        String text = ((Button) v).getText();
        Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + text , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Very Tnks Fouad, but I imagine that one hundred buttons... this not work fine =\

Comment: of course, you can include the other buttons and it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
Button button4= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
text = button4.getText();
```